# Talend guess schema behaviors in two different machine

Tags: talend

I am using Talend 6.0.1. On two different windows machine using similar configuration

- Machine 1 - using windows server
- Machine 2 -is on google cloud

Talend in both are connected to ms SQL server
When I use guess schema Machine1 shows data type as double
for same fields guess schema in Machine2 shows data type as big decimal. 
I have checked the configuration in both machines are similar.
Can anyone help me to find me the reason?

Regards,
V
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdANI.png)

Comment: Are you using the same JDBC driver for both connections? either both should be jtds or microsoft driver.

Comment: I am using jtds connection, Issue is resolved by changing default data type in mssql mapping.xml file. I removed true from the Bigdecimal and it worked.

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks for the update